# uploading images from iphone show up rotated

Tags: iphone, laravel, file-upload, image-uploading

Anyone had an issue with photos uploading sideways or upside down from a phone? It only seems to be when people upload from some phones, when I upload from my computer it works fine:

```
if( $request->file('avatar') ) {
          $path           = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'spaces');
          $avatar         = Storage::disk('spaces')->url($path);
          $user->avatar   = $avatar;

        }
```

I have read its EXIF data being applied. Storing it this way is there a config to set to stop EXIF data?

Comment: take look at this page https://laravel.io/forum/07-16-2014-iphone-image-manipulation-flip-it

Comment: I will try that but does Laravel include Intervention out of the box? I dont think I added that

Answer (score 1):

Use `intervention/image` Package to do this.

Here is an example.

```
if( $request->file('avatar') ) {
      $path           = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'spaces');
      $avatar         = Storage::disk('spaces')->url($path);

     \Intervention\Image\Image::make($avatar)->orientate();

      $user->avatar   = $avatar;

    }
```

Intervention image provides a native method for this.

```
 `\Intervention\Image\Image::make($avatar)->orientate();`
```

Comment: Wouldnt I need to call `Image::make($image)->orientate();` before I uploaded it to my Spaces account? The `$avatar` is just the path